# Why can't I calculate with Number interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I wanted to make such class for calculating average value:

```
  public static class AverageValue<T extends Number> {
    T data = 0;  //ERROR: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T
    int count = 0;
    public AverageValue() {}
    public AverageValue(T data) {
      this.data = data; 
      count = 1;
    }
    public void add(T num) {
      data+=num; //ERROR: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
      count++;
    }
    public T average() {
      return data/(T)count; //ERROR: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T
    }
  }
```

I am not really getting why do we have interface Number if it *doesn't abstract number*. Because that's what interfaces do - abstract operations with data without holding the data themselves.

The above also makes it clear that you'll probably not be ever able to make your own number implementation (eg. number with unlimited size and precision for some really freaky experimental math programs).

I tried the same with `Number` instead of generic `T` with the very same results. Only difference is that `Number x = 0` is actually valid.

Is there a way to trick java to compile this or do I have to be a "professional" java programmer and use doubles to calculate averages on byte arrays?

Comment: `Number` is interface, not primitive type, so it doesn't support these operands. And you don't need to use doubles, just check what actual class is and perform operations on it.

Comment: "Is there a way to trick java to compile" no, `Number` has no special privileges in Java so compiler reacts same way as you would try `Car+Car`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic class for operations on Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940510/generic-class-for-operations-on-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not really getting why do we have interface `Number` if it doesn't abstract number

`interface Number` does abstract the number for the purposes of storing and converting representations. It does not abstract the number for the purposes of making calculations, because the type of the result *representation* is not well defined.

> The above also makes it clear that you'll probably not be ever able to make your own number implementation (eg. number with unlimited size and precision for some really freaky experimental math programs).

`BigDecimal` does it without any problem.

> `Number x = 0` is actually valid.

assigning `Integer` to `Number` is OK. Assigning `Integer` to something that extends `Number` (say, `Double`) is not OK. That's why there is a difference.

> Is there a way to trick java to compile this or do I have to go full <s>retard</s> professional Java programmer and use doubles to calculate averages on byte arrays?

You need to specify the desired representation of the result when you compute the average. You could abstract it out yourself and supply the "averager" ingerface, but the information about the desired representation needs to get into the method in one way or the other:

```
interface AverageMaker<T extends Number> {
    T initialResult();
    T add(T a, Number b);
    T divideByCount(T a, int b);
}

public static <T extends Number, R extends Number> R averageValue(Iterable<T> items, AverageMaker<R> maker) {
    R res = maker.initialResult();
    int count = 0;
    for (T val : items) {
        res = maker.add(res, val);
        count++;
    }
    return maker.divideByCount(res, count);
}
```

Define several average makers, like this:

```
static final AverageMaker<Double> doubleAvg = new AverageMaker<Double>() {
    public Double initialResult() { return 0.0; }
    public Double add(Double a, Number b) { return a + b.doubleValue(); }
    public Double divideByCount(Double a, int b) { return a/b; }
};
static final AverageMaker<Integer> intAvg = new AverageMaker<Integer>() {
    public Integer initialResult() { return 0; }
    public Integer add(Integer a, Number b) { return a + b.intValue(); }
    public Integer divideByCount(Integer a, int b) { return a/b; }
};
```

Now you can use them in your code together with the `averageValue` method:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(4);
a.add(8);
a.add(91);
a.add(18);
double avgDouble = averageValue(a, doubleAvg);
int avgInt = averageValue(a, intAvg);
System.out.println(avgDouble); // Prints 30.25
System.out.println(avgInt);    // Prints 30
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/hx0jF1)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up classes (`Number`) and primitive types (`int`). Operators like `+` or `\` are not supported for numeric classes (`+` is supported for strings, but that's a special case; and unlike e.g. `C#`, Java does not support custom operator overloading).

A "number with unlimited size and precision for some really freaky experimental math programs" is actually supported with the `BigDecimal` class, which shows that (and how) you can indeed have your own `Number` implementation.

Comment: Int is supposed to be Number and java 8 does implicitly cast primitive types to their class counterparts AFAIK.

Comment: Actually `+` is supported with one VIP class which is String :)

Comment: @TomášZato It is automatically boxed/unboxed, but since T can be any numeric type like `Byte` or `Double` compiler can't decide which type should be used to generate code responsible for unboxing `T`.

Comment: @Pshemo: Indeed, my bad ;) I'll try to adjust my answer accordingly, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `double`s in the class. Since the average of `Integers` is a `Double`, this should be correct.

```
public class AverageValue<T extends Number> {

    double data = 0;
    int count = 0;

    public AverageValue() {
    }

    public AverageValue(T data) {
        this.data = data.doubleValue();
        count = 1;
    }

    public void add(T num) {
        data += num.doubleValue();
        count++;
    }

    public double average() {
        return data / count;
    }
}
```

This compiles. Usage:

```
    AverageValue<Integer> avgInt = new AverageValue<>();
    avgInt.add(1);
    avgInt.add(2);
    avgInt.add(3);
    avgInt.add(4);
    System.out.println(avgInt.average());

    AverageValue<Double> avgDouble = new AverageValue<>();
    avgDouble.add(1.1);
    avgDouble.add(1.2);
    avgDouble.add(1.3);
    avgDouble.add(1.4);
    System.out.println(avgDouble.average());
```

Output:

```
2.5
1.25
```

Comment: "*You could work with doubles*"-- and face float-number issues even if all data are integer numbers.

Comment: *If* you want to restrict yourself to a specific class, at least use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou True. But what use is a class that calculates the average of integers without using a double at some point?

Comment: @Marvin BigDecimal for whatß

Comment: @Tichodroma: `BigDecimal` instead of `double`, to be able to get correct results without float-number issues.

Comment: @Tichodroma calculation of avg for long values using double will produce rough result

Comment: @Marvin Feel free to edit my answer.  But I think the question is not about the problems of floating point arithmetic but about `Number` and how it plays with Generics. That's what I've tried to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T

```
T data = (T)(Integer)0;
```

> ERROR: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
>
> ERROR: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T

in java doesn't exist operator overload [Why doesn't Java need Operator Overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559563/why-doesnt-java-need-operator-overloading)